# передается 0 в функцию под button

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Есть функция, которая генерит заданное количество записей в настройках оборудования с частично рандомными значениями. Решил попробовать сделать для нее привычное пользователю окно с помощью Tkinter, но до ввода значений переменных в полях они нулевые, хотя функция должна срабатывать после ввода значений

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import time
import random


window = Tk()
window.title("Add SVLAN Rx")
window.geometry('300x300')

lbl = Label(window, text="Количество svlan rx(1 - 64000):", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

i1 = Entry(window)
i1.grid(column=1, row=0)
i1.focus()
i1 = i1.get()

lb2 = Label(window, text="Ip адрес модема:", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
lb2.grid(column=0, row=1)

addr1 = Entry(window)
addr1_entry = Entry(textvariable=addr1)
addr1_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
addr1 = addr1_entry.get()


def svlan(i1, addr1):
    i = 1
    #addr = str(addr)
    while i != i1:
        i += 1
        s = str(i)
        v = random.randint(2, 4095)
        v1 = str(v)
        response = requests.get('http://'+addr1+'/cx4?da=0&du=65534&dd=' + v1 + '&db=' + s + '&tc=&ta=Apply')
        time.sleep(0.05)


btn = Button(window, text="Сгенерить!", command=svlan(i1, addr1))
btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Ошибка

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" C:/Users/Anton/Desktop/python/express/button.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anton/Desktop/python/express/button.py", line 40, in <module>
    btn = Button(window, text="Сгенерить!", command=svlan(i1, addr1))
  File "C:/Users/Anton/Desktop/python/express/button.py", line 36, in svlan
    response = requests.get('http://'+addr1+'/cx4?da=0&du=65534&dd=' + v1 + '&db=' + s + '&tc=&ta=Apply')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'http:///cx4?da=0&du=65534&dd=2775&db=2&tc=&ta=Apply': No host supplied

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Добавте `lambda` в `Button` `Button(window, text="Сгенерить!", command=lambda: svlan(i1, addr1))`

Comment: уже лучше гораздо, только из поля addr1 никак не принимает значение requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'http:///cx4?da=0&du=65534&dd=2605&db=2&tc=&ta=Apply': No host supplied

Comment: `Button(window, text="Сгенерить!", command=lambda: svlan(i1.get(), addr1.get()))`